# spotfire limit row count of a table visualization

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to limit the number of rows displayed on the visualization by having a property control(input field) in the text area. I was able to create the property control but wondering how to actually apply in the properties window under "Limit data using expression". Is there a way I can specify like RowCount = ${LimitRows} where the LimitRows would be my property control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming LimitRows is a numeric property (integer, real etc.) you can use the expression below to limit the data.

```
rowid()<=${LimitRows}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. I should have mentioned that I am using an expression Rank(rowid(), "asc", [Name], [Value]) to only show distinct rows of my visualization table. I added the rowid() <=${LimitRows} with the AND operator in between. Now the problem is that the rowid() <=${LimitRows} is getting applied on the result set first and then distinct rows are returned. For example, If I requested 10 rows from the input field and if there is a duplicate record then I would only see 9 records instead of 10.

Comment: Originally, what was your limiting expression?

Comment: Originally my limiting expression was using a calculated column(named DupRows) which was calculated using Rank(rowid(), "asc", [Name], [Value]). This calculated column was created to eliminate duplicates based on the two columns Name and Value

My limiting expression said "DupRows=1" and now I changed it to "DupRows=1 and rowid() <=${LimitRows}"

Comment: Ah, OK- below should do it.    Rank(RowId(),[DupRows])<=${LimitRows} and [DupRows]=1